# Yarn: 401 Unauthorized when installing a package from a private repository

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg

I use the private repository built into gitea. The official documentation gives these settings:

```
npm config set {scope}:registry https://gitea.example.com/api/packages/{owner}/npm/
npm config set -- '//gitea.example.com/api/packages/{owner}/npm/:_authToken' "{token}"
```

I generated the token and the package is successfully published through both npm and yarn. But it is only possible to install the package via NPM, Yarn returns 401

```
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://<gitea address>/api/packages/<user>/npm/<package name>/-/1.0.0/<package name>-1.0.0.tgz: Request failed \"401 Unauthorized\"".
```

Given that yarn falls on the link to the TGZ file it has successfully authorized to read the manifest, but is not authorized to download the package. Who has encountered this and how to solve it?

Tried it, it doesn't work:

1. .npmrc, .yarnrc files with scope registry address and auth token
2. Switching to yarn 2 (although this is not even considered a solution)
3. npm login (gitea not have endpoint for this)
4. always-auth true
5. clean npm/yarn cache

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in writing the username, I wrote it in lower case when in gitea it is written in upper case. For some reason this was not a problem for npm. Be careful

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).